# CSS background не хочет уходить на задний план

Tags: css, background

Доброго времени суток!

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. 
Открываем меню => наводим на 1 элемент => background перекрывает другие элементы.
Хз что поделать, уже пол дня бьюсь. Товарищи выручайте пожалуйста.
Строка 176 в CSS.

```css
/*Кнопка меню*/
/* @media screen and (min-width: 614px) {
  .btn_menu {
     display: none;
    }
 } */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

html { overflow-x: hidden; }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.nav_menu {
    width: 75px;
    height: 100%;
 }
}

.nav_menu { 
 width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
 top: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.btn_menu * {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.btn_menu {
    position: absolute;
 top: 20px;
 left: 25px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 50px;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

.btn_menu label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.btn_menu .btn_menu_img {
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.btn_menu .diagonal.part-1 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.btn_menu .horizontal {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.btn_menu .diagonal.part-2 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .horizontal {
    transform: translate(-100px, 0px);
    opacity: 0;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .diagonal.part-1 {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .diagonal.part-2 {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    margin-top: -16px;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu {
 transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.4, -0.4, 0.2, 0.2);
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 display: block;
 background-color: black;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: -25px;
 border-radius: 0;
}

.box_menu {
 transition: ease .4s;
 transition-delay: 1.4s;
 border-radius: 0;
 cursor: default;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: -25px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 
}

.btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li {
 cursor: default;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 20px;
 transition: ease 0.6s;
 font-size: 0;
}

.btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li > a {
 color: #9e8989;
 text-decoration: none;
 z-index: 1000;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li > a {
 color: #9e8989;
 text-decoration: none;
 z-index: 1000;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li > a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 z-index: 1000;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(1) {
 font-size: 36px;
 transition: .6s;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(1) {
 font-size: 0px;
 transition: 1s;
}

body > div > div > label > ul > li > div {
 z-index: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: .5s;
}

body > div > div > label > ul > li > a {
 z-index: 1000;
}

body > div > div > label > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a:hover > div {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background: url(https://www.canvaspop.com/v2/images/2016/office/fuel-space-large.jpg) 100% 100% no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
 z-index: 1;
 opacity: 0.2;
 transition: .5s;
 background-color: transparent;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(2) {
 font-size: 36px;
 transition: .8s;
}

.btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(2) {
 font-size: 0px;
 transition: .8s;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(3) {
 font-size: 36px;
 transition: 1s;
}

.btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(3) {
 font-size: 0px;
 transition: .6s;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(4) {
 font-size: 36px;
 transition: 1.2s;
}

.btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(4) {
 font-size: 0px;
 transition: .4s;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(5) {
 font-size: 36px;
 transition: 1.4s;
}

.btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(5) {
 font-size: 0px;
 transition: .2s;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

<body>
 <div class="nav_menu">
  <div class="btn_menu">
   <input type="checkbox" id="spinner-form4" />
   <label for="spinner-form4" class="btn_menu_img_on">
    <div class="btn_menu_img diagonal part-1"></div>
    <div class="btn_menu_img horizontal"></div>
    <div class="btn_menu_img diagonal part-2"></div>
     <ul class="box_menu">
      <li><a href="#">Текст1<div></div></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Текст1Текст12</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Текст1Текст1Текст13</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Текст1Текст1Текст1Текст14</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Текст1Текст1Текст1Текст1Текст15</a></li>
     </ul>
   </label>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Обьясните, какой результат вам нужен? Если так, что бы фон был скрыт, так не используйте его. Если поправить анимацию, то есть ответ от @Nsk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо так? В правильности решения не очень уверен.

```css
/*Кнопка меню*/
/* @media screen and (min-width: 614px) {
  .btn_menu {
     display: none;
    }
 } */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

html { overflow-x: hidden; }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.nav_menu {
    width: 75px;
    height: 100%;
 }
}

.nav_menu { 
 width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
 top: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.btn_menu * {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.btn_menu {
    position: absolute;
 top: 20px;
 left: 25px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 50px;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

.btn_menu label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.btn_menu .btn_menu_img {
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.btn_menu .diagonal.part-1 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.btn_menu .horizontal {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.btn_menu .diagonal.part-2 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .horizontal {
    transform: translate(-100px, 0px);
    opacity: 0;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .diagonal.part-1 {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .diagonal.part-2 {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    margin-top: -16px;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu {
 transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.4, -0.4, 0.2, 0.2);
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 display: block;
 background-color: black;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: -25px;
 border-radius: 0;
}

.box_menu {
 transition: ease .4s;
 transition-delay: 1.4s;
 border-radius: 0;
 cursor: default;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: -25px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 
}

.btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li {
 cursor: default;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 20px;
 transition: ease 0.6s;
 font-size: 0;
}

.btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li > a {
 color: #9e8989;
 text-decoration: none;
 z-index: 1000;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li > a {
 color: #9e8989;
 text-decoration: none;
 z-index: 1000;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li > a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 z-index: 1000;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(1) {
 font-size: 36px;
 transition: .6s;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(1) {
 font-size: 0px;
 transition: 1s;
}

body > div > div > label > ul > li > div {
 z-index: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: .5s;
}

body > div > div > label > ul > li > a {
 z-index: 1000;
  position: relative;
}

body > div > div > label > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a:hover ~ div {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background: url(https://www.canvaspop.com/v2/images/2016/office/fuel-space-large.jpg) 100% 100% no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
 z-index: 1;
 opacity: 0.2;
 transition: .5s;
 background-color: transparent;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(2) {
 font-size: 36px;
 transition: .8s;
}

.btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(2) {
 font-size: 0px;
 transition: .8s;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(3) {
 font-size: 36px;
 transition: 1s;
}

.btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(3) {
 font-size: 0px;
 transition: .6s;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(4) {
 font-size: 36px;
 transition: 1.2s;
}

.btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(4) {
 font-size: 0px;
 transition: .4s;
}

.btn_menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(5) {
 font-size: 36px;
 transition: 1.4s;
}

.btn_menu_img_on > .box_menu > li:nth-child(5) {
 font-size: 0px;
 transition: .2s;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

<body>
 <div class="nav_menu">
  <div class="btn_menu">
   <input type="checkbox" id="spinner-form4" />
   <label for="spinner-form4" class="btn_menu_img_on">
    <div class="btn_menu_img diagonal part-1"></div>
    <div class="btn_menu_img horizontal"></div>
    <div class="btn_menu_img diagonal part-2"></div>
     <ul class="box_menu">
      <li><a href="#">Текст1</a><div></div></li>
      <li><a href="#">Текст1Текст12</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Текст1Текст1Текст13</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Текст1Текст1Текст1Текст14</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Текст1Текст1Текст1Текст1Текст15</a></li>
     </ul>
   </label>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Это то, что нужно :)